# Android: Adding only two sets of drawables

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is there any way to use only two sets of drawables, one for xxxhdpi and xxhdpi and the other one for xhdpi/hdpi/mdpi/ldpi without having to create 6 drawable-{dpi} folders and duplicating the files.

Comment: How is it duplicating the files if they don't have same drawables. All 6 folders must have different drawables to support devices of different densities. I suggest you go through [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) before posting such quesitons.

Comment: Can't I use a 256px image for a 60dp imageview on a xxxhdpi(240px) and xxhdpi(180px) device?

Comment: Yes you can but it will spoil your layout on actual screen. Did you try and tested it. Automatic resize by android OS is not good and hence it is recommended to create different drawables for different densities. _"However, bitmap scaling can result in blurry or pixelated bitmaps, which you might notice in the above screenshots. To avoid these artifacts, you should provide alternative bitmap resources for different densities"_ Check this [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. 
Use [SVG Images](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) instead of PNG or normal extension pictures. 
Then use the following link to convert the [SVG to Vector](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/).
Use vector as your drawable, your drawable (single) will support multiple devices.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @ibtehaz  Using Vector drawables solved my problem

Comment: @shivendrasingh, pleasure is all mine mate.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Vector drawables are the stuff you mean. The limitation is that it is mostly used for drawing simple shapes.
You can sue it like this. Make a vector drawable for xxhdpi and it'll be used for all resolution sizes with suitable sizes automatically. This technique is currently being used to decrease apk sizes reasonably.